# html to php syntax convert

Tags: php, html

Trying to show a twitter link if the user set their twitter username from the previous page. I can't get the HTML to echo properly with the php tag.
When it echoes.

```
<?php
if($_GET['prof2'] == NULL) {} 
else {
    echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo $_GET["prof2"]; ?>"><?php echo "@" . $_GET["prof2"]; ?>  Twitter</a><br>';
}
?>
```

Where the issue is on my lit profile web page.
http://lit.life/gallry/aidan/586134a88fc4epost.php?profile=image.png&prof=aidangig&title=Just+made+some+changes+between+twitter+and+Lit.Life&video1=&prof2=aidangig&rep=2&text_post=++++++++%0D%0A%09%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%09

**Edit**

I actually just fixed it.

```
echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/'.$_GET["prof2"].'">@'. $_GET["prof2"].' Twitter</a><br>';
```

Comment: You should use the alternative syntax for the ``if()`` statement. It's cleaner than passing HTML to PHP ``echo()``

Comment: You are opening php tag without closing it first. one way is: echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/' . $_GET["prof2"] . '>@' . $_GET["prof2"] . 'Twitter</a><br>';

Comment: @newCodex i applied your change but didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @AidanGignac You haven't replaced the  echo  line properly.

Comment: @newCodex I did. when I replaced the line the page rendered blank. There's an error.

Comment: @AidanGignac sorry my fault. try this: echo '<a href="twitter.com/' . $_GET["prof2"] . '>@' . $_GET["prof2"] . 'Twitter</a><br>';

Comment: You are open to  XSS injections. Also just do `$_GET['prof2'] != NULL` or `!empty($_GET['prof2'])`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/'.$_GET['prof2'].'>@'.$_GET['prof2'].'Twitter</a><br>';
```

Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: no, it didn't echo properly
`<?php echo "@" . $_GET["prof2"]; ?>`
I need that still it shows the user's set twitter to echo and show to the users...

Comment: just modify it, give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if($_GET['prof2'] == NULL) {} 
else {
    echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/'.$_GET["prof2"].'">@'.$_GET["prof2"].' Twitter</a><br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It still shows the same issue of not echoing and the link is also linking to twitter properly...

Answer (score 0):

#### Explaination

You should use the alternative syntax in PHP for your `if()` statement.

It's cleaner, and it's made for mixing HTML and PHP statements.

#### Solution

```
<?php
/* Begin of if statement */
if (NULL != $_GET['prof2']):
?>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo $_GET['prof2']; ?>">@<?php echo $_GET['prof2']; ?> Twitter</a>
<?php
/* End of if statement */
endif;
```

#### Documentation

[PHP : alternative syntax](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: No, the page is rendering blank when I apply that.